# Accents in HTML5 datalist

Tags: html, non-ascii-characters, html-datalist

In a form, I have a text input with a datalist.
In the datalist, I have accented terms that won't appear in my text input. For example :
If I type "a", terms with "ä" or "à" won't appear in suggestion...

The best would be the whole to be accent insensitive

Does anyone encounter that problem already ?

Thank you

Comment: Exactly the same problem I am stuck on right now. @VeZoul did you ever solve this?

Comment: My memory says I solved it using a jQuery plugin... I did not try it since then

Answer (score 1):

One dirty way you can do this is by doing something likes this:

```
var noAccent = str.normalize( "NFD" ).replace( /[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "" );
if (str !== str) {// Add a duplicate entry without the accent}
```